# Prove that there is a group of 1010 people such that every person outside the group knows at least one person in the group.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> In a village there live $2021$ people, some of whom know **each other**. Everyone knows at least one **other** person. Prove that one can find a group of $1010$ people such that everyone outside this group knows at least one person in the group.

I tried small cases like $n=5,7...$ but they don’t work because you can have a case like that with $n=5$, (Denote person $1$ by $P_1$ )
$$P_1\to P_2, P_2\to P_3...P_5\to P_1$$
Where $P_1\to P_2$ Means person $1$ knows person $2$. Now, if you pick any group of $2$ people you will find at least one person outside the group that doesn’t know anyone in the group (You can choose the first person to be $P_1$ since everything is symmetric). So how are we supposed to solve this?

Comment: I guess the author means that everybody knows at least one other person, because if everybody only knows themselves the statement is obviously false. He probably also assumes that 'knowing someone' is a symmetric relation. That'd be questionable, but not indefensible.

Comment: May we presume (1) a person B necessarily knows a person A whenever A knows B, and (2) knowing oneself doesn't count?

Comment: This problem is not well defined. If all the people know Arnold and nobody knows anyone else, then there is no such group.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I’ll post the original problem

Comment: @SuzuHirose Implicit assumption here is that "knows" is two-way. See my answer.

Comment: I know the Queen, but the Queen doesn’t know me.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to showing that the domination number of an $n$-vertex graph with no isolated vertices is at most $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Take a minimum edge cover $C$ of the "knows" graph $G$ the greedy way – adding edges to a maximum matching $M$ to cover exposed vertices, possible since no vertex is isolated.

$C$ is a forest with $|M|$ connected components, since the added edges always connect one exposed vertex to one edge in $M$. But $C$ must also be a forest of stars, for if edges $ab$ and $cd$ are added adjacent to $bc\in M$, $abcd$ is an augmenting path, contradicting $M$'s maximality. The $|M|$ centres of $C$'s stars then dominate $G$, and here $|M|\le\lfloor2021/2\rfloor=1010$.

Comment: What is the domination number of a graph?

Comment: @PNT The minimum possible size of a set of vertices working like the desired group in your question: everyone outside it knows someone inside it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your counterexample is correct. If the people are numbered 1 to 2021, and p knows p+1 except 2021 knows 1, then every person is known to exactly one other person. So if we pick any group G of at most 1010 people, then there are 1010 people knowing anyone in the group. So there are at most 2020 people who are either in G or know someone in G.

Assuming “X knows Y” implies “Y knows X”: Split the 2021 people into two groups A and B; initially A is empty and B is everyone. Then as long as some x in B knows nobody in A, move someone that x knows (x knows some y, which must be in B) from B to A. When eventually everyone in B knows someone in A, either A has 1010 or fewer members. Otherwise, everyone in A knows someone in B, but B has 1010 or fewer members.

Comment: You're interpreting it wrong. OP interpreted it wrong.